# Propagate exception stack from ejb 3 to portlet

Tags: exception, logging, ejb-3.0, portlet

I have a spring mvc portlet that remotely calls an ejb 3. Now when the ejb throws an exception, on the portal side I just see 'EJB Exception'. I do not have access to the actual ejb 3 logs. So what can I do so that the whole exception stack trace is available on the portal side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the EJBException (note that it's a RuntimeException, so, your code is not 'required' to catch it) and then call the [getCausedByException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBException.html#getCausedByException%28%29) method, to have access to the original exception. With it, you can do whatever you want, including rethrow it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it considered a good practice to propagate exceptions across front end and back end like this?

Comment: It depends. Exceptions are exceptions, meaning, they are never a valid outcome. When you are dealing with different software layers, you should always take care of sending the proper information to the other layers. So, if you sent information that one layer thought that was ok, but the other thinks it's not OK, then you have an "exception" :-) Other situations are in "error" conditions, like hardware failures, network issues, and so on. But in those cases, you might want to think twice before leaving the other layer care about those specific details.